# numpy.delete() requires me to return a new matrix (name) and that can't work with my code

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix which is built at the start of the class and then I go on and use within a couple of functions then at the last function I want to delete a row from the matrix without having to use a new variable name for it otherwise I would have to change every single function call (it loops until a winner is found). It sort of works like this

```
matrix defined

...a lot of functions that use it then winner is called

def winner():
    if hasWon():
        .....
    else:
       fun1()

def fun1():
    .....
    Iterativefun()

def Iterativefun():
    .....
    matrix = numpy.delete(matrix, obj,axis)
    winner()
```

Is there a way to delete a row? I thought of changing every single number in that row from 1-10 to a 0 which I'm not using so it would be ignored. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Numpy you have (or exactly what you're trying to do for that matter), but if you have Numpy 1.7, `numpy.squeeze` looks like it might be what you're looking for... http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html#numpy.squeeze

Comment: I've found a small workaround where i have count = 0 at the start and once it runs Iterativefun() for the first time it increments it. Then in my other code i just use.
`if(count =0)
    fun(original matrix)

else 
    fun(new Matrix)`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If changing a row to all zeros is acceptable, you can just use:

```
matrix[row] = 0
```

Comment: It isn't the best solution but I implemented it at the start just so I can move on to more important tasks then I found the solution at the top. Thanks for the help